# Send a request for pdf file from document directory to (POST Method) web service in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, web-services, pdf

I am new to iPhone development, I have a question how to Send a request for pdf file from document directory to Web Service like

```
http://www.publigeee.com/index.php?q=api/upload&uid=1&title=Sample&file=insert Pdf file here
```

How to do insert that pdf file in this link?
I have spend 5 hours for this, but i can't do this, please help me

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Essentially What You are interested is in uploading a file which exist in the document Directory of your application. In the case above your need to upload a PDF file to your server.

I implemented the same for an XML file using the following method -

//This function assumes that the file exist in document directory

```
- (void)uploadXMLFile:(NSString*)sourceFileName atPath:(NSString*)filePath{


    // constructing connection request for url with no local and remote cache data and timeout seconds
    NSURL* scriptURL = [NSURL URLWithString:kFileUploadScriptURL];


    NSMutableURLRequest *request =[NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:scriptURL cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:20];

    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSString *charset = (NSString *)CFStringConvertEncodingToIANACharSetName(CFStringConvertNSStringEncodingToEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding));

    // allocation mem for body data
    NSMutableData* bodyData = [[[NSMutableData alloc] init] autorelease];

    // initializing post body boundary
    NSString *stringBoundary = @"0xKhTmLbOuNdArY";

    // setting request header required
    // request containing multi part form data body and identified charater set encoding
    [request setAllHTTPHeaderFields:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; charset=%@; boundary=%@", charset, stringBoundary],@"Content-Type",
                                     @"gzip",@"Accept-Encoding",nil]];

    // appending body string
    [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // Adds post data

    // Adds files to upload
    // file data identify its content type, data encoding and content disposition 
    // file is identified through its file name on server 
    // file data is retrived from the identified file url

    [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"%@\"; filename=\"%@\"\r\n", @"file", sourceFileName] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Type: %@; charset=%@\r\n\r\n", @"document/xml", charset] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    [bodyData appendData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath]];

    [bodyData appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",stringBoundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // set post body to request
    [request setHTTPBody:bodyData];

    NSString* bodyDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:bodyData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@",bodyDataString);

    // create new connection for the request
    // schedule this connection to respond to the current run loop with common loop mode.

    //  NSURLResponse *response = nil;                    
    //  NSError *error = nil;
    //  NSLog(@"%@",[[[NSString alloc] initWithData: [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&response error:&error] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]autorelease]);

    [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request  delegate:self];
    if (!responseData) {
        self.responseData = [[[NSMutableData alloc] initWithLength:0] autorelease];
    }
}
```

where kFileUploadScriptURL is a constant for server URL

```
#define kFileUploadScriptURL @"SERVER_ADDRESS/upload_file.php"
```

The upload.php essentially holds a PHP script to accept the data and write it to one of the directories on server. Thus an XML file is uploaded to server.You can replace the desired param in the function to set it to upload a PDF.  Since to also wish to other Param like title etc you will have to pass these using HTTP POST.

I am not sure If I can really link my answer with other Questions on SO but [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10952034/how-to-upload-a-file-to-server-stored-in-my-documents-folder-in-ios) one is really close to what you have asked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a HTTP POST - you can't add arbitrary files to the URL (size would kill your request very quickly).

Have a look for ways to HTTP post from iOS - there is lots of this information available.  Also, the site you are referring to (www.publicgee.com) must support the POST method on some end point otherwise you simply can't do it.

So:

1. Find out how www.publigee.com supports POST
2. Change your code to use a HTTP POST operation to send the file